# exec bash command in .profile file not letting Control-M job to run

Tags: unix, control-m

I have an issue where my Control-M job is not able to execute anything on the unix box.

after investigation found out that .profile file in the unix server is the culprit.

content of the .profile file is

exec bash

I tried renaming the file and run the job in UAt and it did work where as I am not sure whats the implication of not having this file.

Can some one pls help me with explaining

what would be the overall impact if I rename the .profile file

how the content of .profile file being used in the server

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what this "Control-M" thing is, but you should be able to safely remove that one-line `.profile` from your account with no problem.  All it does is replace whatever command shell is assigned by default to your account with the command shell called `bash`.  If you don't care if you use the default shell or `bash`, and especially if you are having problems with that `.profile` file, then just remove it.

If you really want to use `bash` then you might try changing your default shell with the `chsh` command.  That may also cause problems for this "Control-M" thing, so you'll want to read the `chsh` manual page to be sure you know how to determine what your current shell is and how to change back to the original value if there are any problems.